# Sending a Pull Request to a GitHub repo when already a collaborator

Tags: git, github

This might sound slightly strange, but I want to ask how you can submit a PR to a cloned GitHub repo when you already have collaborator/write access to the original repository.

I know how to create a PR already with topic branches and such, but when it comes to performing a `git push` this will be pushed directly to the main repo. In this instance I want it to be reviewed by another team member, what should I do to prevent this so it gets pushed to my clone and then I can create the PR request via GitHub and not directly commit the changes.

In addition I want everything to be contained within my clone and not pushing topic branches to the main repo.

Will I need to adjust the origin/remote values? What's the best way to perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either commit to a topic branch and create the PR within the main repository, or you can add your clone as a second remote and then explicitly push to your clone.

Comment: It would have to be the latter, I don't want to create any new branches on the main repo, everything should be contained within my clone to then send the PR.

Comment: Well then do as I said, add your clone as a second remote and push to it, easy as pie :-)

Comment: Like this `git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myclonedrepo.git`?

Comment: You miss the name of the remote between `add` and the url

Comment: My bad, would I need to remove the current `origin` values that are returned by `git remote -v` or can specify which one to push to, in order to create the PR in GitHub?

Comment: You can have 50 remotes if you so wish, no need to delete anything. The most usual convention is to name your forks remote `origin` and the main repo `upstream` if you work with PRs.

Comment: But in this case if I change the `origin` to my fork and put the main repo as `upstream` (which is currently `origin`) my git push will go to my fork rather than the main repo right?

Answer (score 0):

Your push will go to where you tell it to or where you configured it to, no matter how the remotes are called.